# ASP pages not bringing in Images, CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic

My uncle's has got the files for his website that he got made a few years ago and needs something changed on it. So he has sent me the files as I am willing to make small changes as I know HTML and CSS. But when I open his index.asp page in a browser this only shows html even though the images, css and javascript files are linked properly.

I am not familiar with asp, I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know why the files are not being brought up when I open the index.asp file in a browser.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the site through IIS in localhost? ASP is compiled at the server (or computer) level.

Comment: This is a pretty open ended question as without seeing any of the code, folder structure, etc.. it could be anything.  More then likely though as EmCo pointed out your paths to images, CSS, and JS is incorrect.

Comment: /images/image.jpg does not reference the website it references the root directory so if you only downloaded the site and didn't download the directory and it subfolders as well then it won't show the images.

Comment: @motoxer4533 no i'm just running it off my desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you just open the asp file on a browser, there's no web server intervention so that the ASP page is properly processed. You are just opening a file as if you were opening it on Notepad. You need to configure the whole site as an IIS Application and browse to the site by going to `http://localhost/YourSite`

Answer (score 1):

First things first - as the previous comment says, you need to run ASP through an IIS based web site because the code needs to be processed.

If you're running through IIS and having this issue, check to see that your IIS settings are correct. Google "static content IIS" and you should find articles relating to this problem.